Which should be used to calculate voltage gain (\$1+g_m\ r_O\$) in this schematics below? left or right?
The following is from the book RF MICROELECTRONICS Page 47.
Calculate the input-referred noise of the common-gate stage depicted in Fig. 2.46(a).
Assume I1 is ideal and neglect the noise of \$R_1\$.

voltage gain of the stage is given by \$1+g_m\ r_O\$
The author hasn't explained how he derive this voltage gain.
Which should be used to calculate voltage gain (\$1+g_m\ r_O\$) in  this schematics below?
left or right?

I think the left should be chosen when we have to calculate voltage gain.

This schematic can be further simplified to a source (\$V_{in}\$) in series with a resistor (\$R_{1}\$) since we know the current through M1 is 0.
$$\frac{V_{out} - V_{in}} {r_O} - V_{in} g_{m1} = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}} = g_{m1}\ r_O +1$$

The prerequisite for that book is a fundamentals of microelectronics textbook, which seemingly you have not gone through yet. If you struggle with your fundamentals in analog circuits, RF and AMS will become a mess for you. Anyway, the schematic on the right shorts $V_{in}$ to GND. Not very helpful, is it?

@a360pilot Is my equation correct? $$\frac{V_{out} - V_{in}} {r_O} - V_{in} g_{m1} = 0$$

yes, which results in the correct gain equation. What puzzles me is why you even suggest using the schematic on the right.

@a360pilot
The right one comes from figure (b) in the figure. And what's more, the one from Raonoke suggests me that is wrong.

@a360pilot Can you take a look at  my answer to this question below? Do you think this analysis is in the right track?

figure (b) is analyzing the noise. Figure (a) analyzes the voltage gain. How are these figures expected to be the same?! You use each for its own purpose!

@a360pilot Can you take a look at my answer? Raonoke believed that i am wrong.


From the nodal equation

$$(\frac{v_o} {R_d} + \frac{v_o - v_i} {r_o}) + g_m  v_{gs} = 0$$
with \$v_i = -v_{gs}\$ and after some rearranging:
$$v_o  (\frac{1} {R_d} + \frac{1} {r_o}) = v_i  (\frac{1} {r_o} + g_m)$$

Voltage gain \$A_v\$ is:

$$A_v = \frac{v_o} {v_i} = (1 + g_m r_o) * [\frac{R_d} {r_o + R_d}]$$

In your case drain load Rd = infinite, which means:

$$A_v = (1 + g_m ro)$$

With a finite drain load \$R_d\$ and \$R_d \ll r_o\$ as a constraint:

$$A_v \approx g_m R_d$$

Which schematic did you use for nodal equation? Left or Right?

In my opnion. $$\frac{V_{out} - V_{in}} {r_O} - V_{in} g_{m1} = 0$$ using KCL

Shorting out vin/vgs in the schematic on the right and having a division by zero for Av is imo not helpful at all. I used only the relevant stuff: vin, transistor and load Rd. Your "opinion" comes into play by leaving out Rd altogether.

After you simplified down the circuit, how do you determine the gain from just Vin and R1?

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}} = (g_{m1}\ r_O +1)$$

it seems that your nodal equation assumes the current through source is 0.
$$I_{in} = 0$$

take a look at my answer post.

It's impossible to arrive at a gain of 1+gm*ro after you literally eliminated the transistor and nothing is left but a voltage source (Vi) and a resistor (R1).

you literally eliminated the transistor and nothing is left" This is according to KCL.

Take this general form below for example.
We have two KCL here.
$$\frac{{V_{in} - V_x}} {R_S} + \frac{V_{out} - V_x} {r_O} - V_x g_m = \frac{V_x} {R_1}$$
$$\frac{V_{out} - V_x} {r_O} - V_x g_m = \frac{V_{out}} {R_L}$$
$$A_v = \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}} = \frac{R_1 R_L (1 + g_m\ r_O)} {R_1 R_L + R_1 r_O + R_1 R_S + R_L R_S + r_O R_S + g_m\ R_1 r_O R_S}$$
When \$R_L \to \infty\$ which means open circuit (current source in small signal analysis is open), \$R_S \to 0\$ which means short circuit. This is exactly what is shown in book RF MICROELECTRONICS Page 47.
$$\lim_{R_L\to\infty, R_S \to 0} \frac{R_1 R_L (1 + g_m\ r_O)} {R_1 R_L + R_1 r_O + R_1 R_S + R_L R_S + r_O R_S + g_m\ R_1 r_O R_S} = 1 + g_m\ r_O$$
Code I use to solve \$A_v\$ in Wolfram Mathematica.
eq1 = (Vin - Vx)/RS + (Vout - Vx)/rO - Vx gm == Vx/R1;
eq2 = (Vout - Vx)/rO - Vx gm == -Vout/RL;
sols = Solve[eq1 && eq2, {Vx, Vout}]

Again = (Vout/Vin) /. sols[[1, 2]]
Limit[Again, RL -> Infinity]
Limit[Again, {RL -> Infinity, RS -> 0}]


Is this an answer or an edit?

@VoltageSpike An answer to my own question

Making Rs=0 is not equivalent to a short circuit at the input like you are showing in the hand-drawn schematic on the right side in your original post.

As @Raonkoe correctly pointed out, you are indeed using the figure on the left. It is not a question of equations, your equations are correct. However, your original post asks which figure to use, and you are using the one on the left, perhaps without even realizing it. Therefore, figure (a) is the one that will be used for gain calculation. As a side note, figure (b) is not what you drew on the image on the right.

@a360pilot But Raonke said this nodal equation where I disagree.
$$(\frac{v_o} {R_d} + \frac{v_o - v_i} {r_o}) + g_m  v_{gs} = 0$$
In my opnion, it should be
$$\frac{v_o - v_i} {r_o} + g_m  v_{gs} = 0$$

Wouldn't they be the same when $R_D\to\infty$? He is trying to break the problem down and solve it in more intuitive steps. You can either do that or write the answer by inspection. But this is not what you originally asked in my opinion.
